# How to manage data at DO Spaces with Laravel Storage

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I am trying to manage DO's Spaces with Laravel's 8 Storage, however I am getting errors which seems to come from Laravel's side.

At start I wrote this line in terminal as I was instructed in Laravel's documentation
`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "~1.0"`

afterwards I edited my environmental variables

```
DO_SPACES_KEY=*KEY*
DO_SPACES_SECRET=*SECRET*
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACES_REGION=AMS3
DO_SPACES_BUCKET=test-name
```

also added changes in config/filesystems.php

```
'do_spaces' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
            'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
            'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
        ],
```

After visiting this test Route

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    Storage::disk('do_spaces')->put('test.txt', 'hello world');
});
```

I am getting this error

---

Error executing "PutObject" on "//test-name./test-name/test.txt"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'test-name' (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://test-name./test-name/test.txt

---

It seems that problem occurs while laravel is trying to compile url which should not look as it is here (wrong - *http://test-name./test-name/test.txt*). However I have no clue how to fix this issue and what I am doing wrong, since I was following all steps as many tutorials and documetations were telling to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it next way:

Add https:// to DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT (https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com)

In put method use path to text.txt:

Storage::disk('do_spaces')->put('YOUR_SPACE_NAME/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME(if you have)/test.txt', 'hello world');